# Prominent non-mathematical work of mathematicians

Tags: soft-question, big-list

First of all, sorry if this post is not appropriate for this forum.

I have a habit that every time I read a beautiful article I look at the author's homepage and often find amazing things.

Recently I read a paper of [Andrew Hicks](https://www.math.drexel.edu/%7Eahicks/) and when I opened his homepage I found many links about his invention: [Flawless wing mirrors (car mirror)](https://www.math.drexel.edu/%7Eahicks/media.html).

[image]
([Image Source](https://www.math.drexel.edu/%7Eahicks/))

I would not be surprised if this invention was made by a non-mathematician. His mirror is an amazing invention to me because every day I see it, but didn't know its inventor is a mathematician! Anyway, I want to ask

> **Question 1:** Are there mathematicians who have done outstanding/prominent non-mathematical work like inventions, patents, solving social/economical/etc. problems, papers in these areas, etc.?

Of course, one can say that almost all technology nowadays is based on the work of mathematicians, but I'm asking for specific contributions/innovations.

I want to ask a similar question (Maybe it will be useful for those who are looking for a job!):

> **Question 2:** Which mathematicians are working in non-mathematical areas/companies?

Note: Please add to your answers the name and the work of the mathematician.

Comment: Unabomber has to be #1 on this list.

Comment: Not clear if it fits, but Emanuel Lasker was a Chess World Champion and a mathematician. I understand that he proved some important results in Commutative Algebra.

Comment: You may consider Sir Isaac Newton. Apart from his mathematical discoveries he did many non mathematical inventions. He built telescope, worked with Alchemy, was involved in politics.

Comment: A good question here would need good delineation of "mathematician" and of "non-mathematical work". In the absence of that, I find this vague and I've downvoted

Comment: The question is too vague. Before 18 century, all mathematicians had non-mathematical jobs since there were no mathematical jobs.So probably you mean modern times. It is also not clear who exactly is counted as a mathematician.

Comment: @Piyush if we put Unabomber on the list, then we should also make room for André Bloch, mathematician and triple murderer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/André_Bloch_(mathematician)

Comment: @GerryMyerson, not necessarily.  Bloch was a murderer first, and did his mathematics while institutionalized (not to mention that murder isn't usually considered "non-mathematical work").  On the other hand, Kaczynski was a mathematician first, and his later non-mathematical work was a sociological thesis on the inevitability of human enslavement by industrial society.

Comment: @Ray Are you saying murder IS considered mathematical work?!

Comment: @HarryWilson There’s mathematical work, there’s non-mathematical work, and then there are other things than work.

Comment: I’m not sure whether Jean van Heijenoort would qualify. He was a Trotskyist activist and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_van_Heijenoort?wprov=sfti1 says he also was personal secretary and bodyguard of Trotsky.

Comment: @HarryWilson, The bombings and deaths were mostly an irrelevant side effect (from TK's point of view). That was simply a means of getting his work published. Remember, he was abused by his parents and as an under-aged student by his university professors, and was tortured and brainwashed by the CIA's "MK Ultra" mind-control program. His mathematical publications were legitimate, though not major breakthroughs, his *Industrial Society and its Future* is a not unreasonable sociological analysis, its purpose being to present the world with its only possible chance of avoiding inevitable slavery.

Comment: @RayButterworth: This comment thread is rapidly getting both off-topic and speculative. (For instance, the accusation that your comment contains about Kaczynski's parents is not supported by the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ted_Kaczynski) about Ted Kaczynski, and neither by a quick google search that I did for his name.) I do not want to be rude, but I would really appreciate it if we could keep this comment thread focussed on the question rather than on claims that are speculative or off-topic (or both).

Comment: Elena Ventsel (Russian: Елена Сергеевна Вентцель) was a mathematician working in probability theory and operations research. Besides her scientific output, she also authored several monographs and textbooks. And she was also an accomplished fiction writer publishing under the pen name of Irina Grekova (Russian: Ирина Грекова). By the way, this pen name is mathematical: if you write this name as the first name initial and the last name, it's **I.Grekova** (Russian: **И.Грекова**) -- from "igrek" (Russian: "игрек"), which is the Russian name of the letter "y".

Comment: I wonder if Brendan McKay's work on debunking the Bible Code counts.  See: [John Safran vs God - Bible Code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7tXK5atEuTA).

Comment: I think Eric Lander deserves a mention

Comment: No pun intended, but isn't Persi Diaconis quite high up in Magic Circles?

Comment: @Geoff I thought of Persi, I agree he'd be a good answer. (But I've already posted four.)

Comment: Why no John von Neumann? One of the most prominent and versatile mathematician of 20th centure. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_von_Neumann

Comment: Surely there must be mathematicians who are also famous for their work as translators? I can well-imagine mathematicians translating old writings just for fun, and I feel like I've heard stories, but can't think of any off the top of my head.

Comment: @Beta: [it has been posted before here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/369737/90655)!!

Comment: Perhaps, you could append your *Question* by the alphabetic list of mathematicians that were already mentioned in this thread.

Answer (score 90):

Samuel Eilenberg, one of the key mathematicians of the XX Century (co-created category theory, systematized homological algebra, opened new roads in topology, etc), was a good example:

**he had (at least) TWO LIVES, with only one thing in common, his short name, Sammy.**

In the first one he was the mathematician, whereas in the other he was a formidable expert and collector of Chinese and far-eastern ancient pottery (and other artifacts as well). He was world-famous in his second life just like he was in his first one (when he died he donated his immense collection to NYC, you can still admire it  [here](https://www.metmuseum.org/art/metpublications/The_Lotus_Transcendent_Indian_and_Southeast_Asian_Art_from_the_Samuel_Eilenberg_Collection)).

What is funny (and a bit odd ) is this: Sammy did not like to mix his two lives at all. At his funeral, the two groups (mathematicians and art collectors) collided for the first and last time. Nobody could believe that Prof. Eilenberg, the Math Genius, and Prof. Eilenberg, one of the greatest authorities in ancient eastern arts, were one and the same man.

**POST SCRIPT**

I have done some research on Sammy's life as art collector: apparently, he was struck by the beauty of indian art during a trip to India. From that point on, he decided that he had to assemble a collection of eastern art and craftmanship, which he did in the next 30 + years. Now I finally see what the two Eilenberg had in common: a passion for aesthetics, for the formal beauty of structures. Alex Heller wrote the following words to honor his Teacher Sammy:

**As I perceived it, then, Sammy considered that the highest value in mathematics was to be found, not in specious depth nor in the overcoming of overwhelming difficulty, but rather in providing the definitive clarity that would illuminate its underlying order. This was to be accomplished by elucidating the true structure of the objects of mathematics. Let me hasten to say that this was in no sense an ontological quest: the true structure was intrinsic to mathematics and was to be discerned only by doing more mathematics. Sammy had no patience for metaphysical argument. He was not a Platonist; equally, he was not a non-Platonist. It might be more to the point to make a different distinction: Sammy’s mathematical aesthetic was classical rather than romantic.**

Comment: One might say that, because of his contributions to the theory of finite automata, he was also a computer scientist which, if we don't consider this part of mathematics, is a third domain of specialty.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Then I might  also add *Edward Spanier* to the list. Also more known as a mathematician; but  published fundamental, and much cited, work in theoretical computer science; mostly with S. Ginsburg. Eilenberg's work in automata theory is clearly written and still inspirational after almost 50 years, but most TCS-Researchers know that he is a famous mathematician too. However, Spanier, I guess  most TCS people do not know that he is a mathematician at all. At least it is not that well-known.

Comment: @StefanH A small thing, but it's Edwin, not Edward, Spanier.

Comment: @DannyRuberman Oh yes, I am sorry. Thank you!

Answer (score 63):

Charles Lutwidge Dodgson (1832-1898), better known as [Lewis Carroll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_Carroll).

Comment: please expand, Noam :-). surely you can name a few things done/invented/made by Dodgson which you find outstanding...

Comment: Well, probably his universally-known fictional books qualify for "outstanding/prominent non-mathematical work", or am I missing something?

Comment: I think the issue is whether this is a prominent non-mathematical work of a professional mathematician, or a prominent mathematical work of a non-mathematician, or if that matters for this question. Certainly in this case his novels are more famous than his math.

Comment: @BradyGilg His day job was as a mathematician. That most people don't know it doesn't make him any less of one :).

Comment: Fun fact: The mad hatters in Alice in Wonderland were meant to make fun of other mathematicians he knew of.

Comment: If we had to quibble, it would be by saying that a mathematics lecturer at Oxford at the time wasn't expected to be a mathematician in the modern sense (i.e., a research mathematician). He did do a bit of research (I once used a lemma on his on determinants), but apparently didn't really try to be part of the research community (and there was such a thing in the UK at the time, though nothing compared to France or Germany). At any rate, that's really quibbling - Noam's answer is of course right, and we should be happy to call Dodgson a mathematician.

Comment: I've also used Dodgson condensation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodgson_condensation in one of my own papers.  He certainly counts as a research mathematician in practice even if he technically wasn't one on paper.

Comment: The White Knight in _Looking Glass_ is often thought to be his caricature of himself. But the part of the White Knight's speech beginning with 'The name of the song is called "_Haddocks' Eyes_"' I've seen used as a good illustration of pointers and indirection in computer science.

Answer (score 51):

Noam D. Elkies, who gave an answer to this question, is himself also an accomplished composer.

Comment: Interesting. Is he currently active in mathematics?

Comment: OMG. He is also winner of the 1996 World Chess Solving Championship!! duo to wiki.

Comment: I think it would be topologically satisfying if Noam could write something about the achievement in physics of some mathematician gmvh ;-).

Comment: Although he states his rating is nothing to brag about, he's also a chess master.  Take it from a guy that has been playing casually since age 5, that isn't an easy feat.

Answer (score 51):

I have noticed, after reading all previous answers, that no woman mathematician was listed.

My first impression is that most women mathematician born before 1960 (or maybe until today), are outstanding in non mathematics areas as they must have been activist for just having the chance of studying. Many of them were not even recognized or could work as mathematicians, because universities didn't hire women professors. A sad example is that of Emmy Noether who taught for seven year without income from the university. But besides this, there are many women contributing for medicine and biology, social equity, and inclusions of minorities in mathematics. But they are ghosts, as we do not see or know them. Here is a list with some of them: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_women_in_mathematics

Here are two examples:
Sophie- Germain, who, besides being a important mathematician of her time, contributed to elasticity theory and to philosophy - her philosophical work were admired and cited by Auguste Comte. She has struggled to study in her time but were recognized by the great mathematicians Lagrange and Gauss, even after they discovered that she was not Monsieur LeBlanc. ( Her history is worth reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain )

More recently, we have Eugenia Cheng, who is a category theorist and an accomplished pianist. She is also a writer engaged in mathematical popularization and has a column in The Wall Street Journal.

Comment: I went to a mathematics lecture by Eugenia once and she played the keyboard in the middle of it ;)

Comment: Kovalevskaya had manifold interests and wrote a novel, but apparently it was not very good (to go by my memories of what is stated in Ann Hibner Koblitz's excellent biography, which I unfortunately don't have at hand). Perhaps we need a separate question on "first-rate mathematicians who can't focus and keep doing non-outstanding work in other fields", taking care of course not to forget elements of the set who are women.

Comment: Wouldn't Ada Lovelace qualify?  Does writing software fall under non mathematical work?

Comment: "Kovalevskaya had manifold interests" Pun intended, @HAH?

Comment: Lilian Pierce has also introduced musical interludes in her mathematical talks. She won the 2018 Sadosky Prize for research that "spans and connects a broad spectrum of problems ranging from character sums in number theory to singular integral operators in Euclidean spaces" including in particular "a polynomial Carleson theorem for manifolds". She is an associate professor of mathematics at Duke University, and a von Neumann Fellow at the Institute for Advanced Study. By age 11 she began performing professionally as a violinist. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lillian_Pierce

Comment: We will probably need a separate, (very) long list of "mathematicians who are talented instrumentalists".

Comment: @HAHelfgott I see, you like being in lists:)

Answer (score 45):

Fields medallist Cédric Villani is a French politician.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematician-politicians has a long list of people who "achieved notability both as academically-trained mathematicians (with a graduate degree, or published in mathematical journals) and also as elected politicians (at a state or national level)." Daniel Biss was a member of the Illinois Senate. Kathleen Ollerenshaw was Lord Mayor of Manchester. Paul Painlevé was Prime Minister of France.

Comment: The mathematician Borel was a cabinet member under the mathematician Painleve, who was Prime Minister of France.

Comment: I don't believe that a mathematician can work as politician successfully. because if you take a glimpse of what most of politicians have done during the history by deceiving, lying, non-logical offering against other countries, hypocrisy, etc (e.g. USA and Br or even Fr) while a mathematician cannot left his/her logic.

Comment: @C.F.G there is no shortage of deceiving, lying, hypocritical and/or illogical mathematicians.

Comment: @C.F.G There is nothing stopping a mathematician from asserting something he or she believes to be untrue in the hope of ultimately gaining something from this deception ("suppose for a contradiction that ... ")

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahmed_Chalabi#Western_education

Comment: Paul Painlevé was also the first person to be an airplane passenger in France.

Comment: @GerryMyerson also worth noting that there do exist some quite successful non-deceiving, non-lying, non-hypocritical, non-illogical politicians (although to be fair, there is in fact a shortage of such).

Comment: @C.F.G: Mathematicians are human beings, with biases and beliefs like every other human being. For example about the current economical system: is it efficient? How can we fix/improve it? What fraction of mathematicians read peer-reviewed academic literature on economics?

Comment: @C.F.G It's very easy to do that without leaving logic: Axiom 1: I want money; Axiom 2: I want power; Axiom 3: Me > anybody else. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Of course they are human but [watch this](https://youtu.be/f7p5PdN-vbE?t=10) for a moment.

Comment: The politic is not similar to math. A mathematician can work alone successfully, but being successful politician depend on the other powerful countries. Of course it is not too hard being successful politician if you are US alliance. I don't want to to turn discussion into politic.

Comment: But he hasn't done anything as a politician. Seating in the parliamant to sleep and gulp down your 5000 euros (after tax) every month can't count as "proeminent non-mathematical work".

Comment: @Libli I confess that I only have an existence proof of his political career, and know nothing about its success or otherwise.

Answer (score 41):

[Omar Khayyam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omar_Khayyam) was a Persian mathematician, astronomer, philosopher, and poet. As a mathematician, he is most notable for his work on the classification and solution of cubic equations, where he provided geometric solutions by the intersection of conics. Khayyam also contributed to the understanding of the parallel axiom. As a poet, he gave us the [Rubaiyat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubaiyat_of_Omar_Khayyam) of Omar Khayyam – "A Jug of Wine, a Loaf of Bread—and Thou."

Comment: +1. [Rubaiyat in MIT website](http://classics.mit.edu/Khayyam/rubaiyat.html)?

Comment: Yes, that's the one.

Comment: He was also one of the contributors to [Solar Hijri calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_Hijri_calendar) which is more accurate than the Gregorian calendar. (The GC has 1 day non-accurate after 3320 years while SHC has 1 day non-accurate after 3770 years!!)

Comment: I think it is not clear that the mathematician Khayyam is the same as poet Khayyam. at least in Iran, I hear arguments about it between historians.

Answer (score 40):

[Jim Simons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Simons_(mathematician)) - probably best known to mathematicians for his work on the [secondary characteristic classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern%E2%80%93Simons_form) developed various mathematical models for market trading that have been highly successful. He is an outstanding philanthropist, using much of the income from his financial engineering work to support lots of research activities through e. g. the [Simons foundation](https://www.simonsfoundation.org/): the [Simons investigators awardees list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simons_Foundation#Simons_Investigators_awardees) includes such names as Aaronson, Aganagic, Bhargava, Daubechies, Eskin, Kapustin, Katzarkov, Kitaev, Mirzakhani, Okounkov, Ooguri, Poonen, Rouquier, Seidel, Tao, ...

Comment: By "best known" I assume you mean best known published mathematics? The Medallion Fund, Renaissance Tech, and the Simons foundation are more well known overall by a factor of thousands.

Comment: @BradyGilg Thanks, tried to clarify. Feel free to edit it, it is community wiki

Comment: From the known histories, the early strategies used by Medallion Fund (which became the basis for Renaissance Technologies) were derived basically by James Ax.  Later strategies were created by Elwyn Berlekamp.  It seems Simons' contributions were more in the business and management aspects.  Not saying this to lessen him.  Realistically, given the lack of success Berlekamp had later in finance, management (and hiring) practices may be more significant than actual strategies.  I think this is also more inline with the intent of the question.

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh Robert Mercer is an electrical engineering PhD who also made significant contributions to Renaissance Tech, but much greater contributions to digital image processing. I did not know about James Ax. Thank you!

Answer (score 36):

[Anna Kiesenhofer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anna_Kiesenhofer) is a mathematician at Lausanne. She works in PDE, and has nine publications listed at researchgate.

She just won a gold medal in cycling at the Tokyo Olympics.

Comment: see also https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/5102/11260

Comment: This deserves a separate thread, on mathematicians who are into sports. Incredible achievement!

Answer (score 33):

[Emanuel Lasker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emanuel_Lasker) was a great mathematician and is regarded as one of the best chess players ever. If it counts.

Comment: Lasker is mentioned in one of the comments on the original post.

Comment: I think it's appropriate for that comment to be turned into an answer, especially since it's CW.

Comment: And indeed World Chess Champion from 1894 to 1921, the longest period of time anyone has been World Chess Champion.

Comment: Interesting! I knew him first as a chess player - I didn't know that he was also a mathematician.

Comment: Emanuel Lasker was a great chess player, one of the best ever, and a not insignificant mathematician: he proved a basic result on ideal theory - it's familiar (in a more general form due to Noether) to anybody who has taken a course in algebraic number theory.

Comment: I think @HAHelfgott's comment gets it right: not a great mathematician, but a not insignificant mathematician.

Comment: Another way to put it is that he was someone who had an excellent paper a couple of years after his thesis, unfortunately never got a permanent job, and decided to focus on other things (including one at which he was the greatest of his age).

Comment: Max Euwe was also a wolrd champion in Chess, had a PhD in mathematics and was a professor of Computing Science at Rotterdam U.

Comment: Here is a link to [another answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369672/prominent-non-mathematical-work-of-mathematicians/369956#369956) mentioning Emanuel Lasker.

Answer (score 32):

[Tom Lehrer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Lehrer) published a couple of papers in mathematical statistics, and taught Mathematics at University of California, Santa Cruz for many years, but is undoubtedly better known for his three albums of humorous songs.

Comment: Let us not forget his work on analytic and algebraic topology of locally Euclidian metrization of infinitely differentiable Riemannian manifolds.

Comment: @Aurelio : And this, he knew from nothing!

Comment: Incidentally, Lehrer has recently put all his lyrics in the public domain, and made them available for download until 2024. https://tomlehrersongs.com

Answer (score 31):

[Bertrand Russell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_Russell) was a mathematician well-known for his philosophical and political work.

Comment: Bertrand Russell was a philosopher who did also some math. His work in philosophy is still taught, his work in mathematics is not.

Comment: @Michael The *Principia* are still a well-researched subject. The interest in it is by no means just historical.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker : Russell's type theory is still sometimes taught since type theory is the foundation of certain programming languages and proof assistants.

Comment: @TimothyChow: those programming languages and proof assistants are based on descendants of *Church’s* type theory.  Russell’s type theory was very different, and I’ve never heard of it being taught in this connection.  That said, I agree that Principia continues to be very relevant.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Can you point me to some modern mathematical research on PM?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker The question is about "prominent non-mathematical works of mathematicians", not "non-mathematical works of prominent mathematicians". If someone dismissed your own work as "not being taught anymore" in 2070, would you think this were appropriate? He wrote a three-volume book on the foundations of mathematics, he was a mathematician (among other things).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi My point is that by all reasonable standards Russell was a philosopher who also did some math (with Whitehead) that grew out of his philosophical work. TO me this answer reads a bit like "Edward Witten is a mathematician well-known for his work in physics."

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker If a Fields medalist does not deserve the title "mathematician" by your standards, I am not sure we are going to get anywhere with this discussion. I don't know why you are so insistent that if someone is to be described as a mathematician then that's all they should be.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Surely Russell's paradox is still relevant (even if it may be the Russell-Zermelo paradox...).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I have no problem with calling Witten a mathematician in many contexts, his Fields medal is obviously why I have chosen him as an example. I have a problem with calling someone a "a mathematician who also did X" if X was what the person did primarily. I would find it less objectionable to describe Russell as a mathematician and a philosopher instead of describing him as a mathematician that also did philosophy. It is belittling other fields and that is what I object to.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica You are right. Proving Frege's system inconsistent was of major mathematical importance.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker No one else but you wrote that anyone is "a mathematician who also did X"... The OP wrote that Russell was "mathematician well-known for his philosophical and political work" which makes it very clear that Russell is... well-known for his philosophical and political works, implicitly not his math. Since your objection is about phrasing more than substance, at least quote things correctly...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi My objection is about substance. If we consider all instances in which someone whose primary work lied outside of mathematics but who did also math as an example, the list would certainly explode. I am sorry if understood what I wrote as a direct quote.

Comment: I don't understand the distinction, can a person not be both a philosopher and a mathematician?  (Leibniz is the best example).

Comment: You know you’ve made it when people spend inordinate amounts of time arguing whether you were a mathematician who did philosophy or a philosopher who did mathematics, all the while completely ignoring your Nobel Prize in Literature.

Comment: @DanRomik: Not when it is idolization rather than actual acknowledgement of real contribution.

Comment: Russell himself was apparently insecure about his status as a mathematician. According to Littlewood (in the posthumous edition of his *Miscellany*) "He had a secret craving to have proved *some* straight mathematical theorem."
Littlewood goes on: "As a matter of fact there *is* one: $2^{2^a} > \aleph_0$ if $a$ is infinite. Perfectly good mathematics."

Answer (score 30):

From [Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Grassmann) Hermann Günther Grassmann (German: Graßmann, pronounced [ˈhɛʁman ˈɡʏntɐ ˈɡʁasman]; 15 April 1809 – 26 September 1877) was a German polymath, **known in his day as a linguist** and now also as a mathematician.

Comment: May be it should be said that he left Mathematics disappointed by the reception  of his work and because his posibilities of teaching math were very low due to really bad reports, for example by Kummer. His book was almost ignored for more than two decades; now it is considered the father of linear algebra.

Comment: @Xarles, have you read Kummer's report, and if so, do you know if it can be found online? What you wrote is a common narrative; I also heard another one - that Kummer's report was completely accurate, and whatever in Grassmann's writing we now deem important was buried in the many pages of his unclear, unrigorous and hardly readable text. I have no opinion of my own though.

Comment: When I looked into Grassmann's book **Die Lineale Ausdehnungslehre, ein neuer Zweig der Mathematik** from 1844, my impression was, that he aimed to explain his ideas and results to philosophers like Kant. The second edition **Die Ausdehnungslehre. Vollständig und in strenger Form begründet** from 1862 seems  already like a standard text on linear algebra.

Answer (score 29):

Felix Hausdorff wrote philosophical works, essays, poems and plays under the pseudonym Paul Mongré. Let me quote from the information of the Hausdorff Center for Mathematics in Bonn:

https://www.hcm.uni-bonn.de/about-hcm/felix-hausdorff/about-felix-hausdorff/

> Hausdorff pursued, especially during the early years in Leipzig, a
> kind of double identity: as Felix Hausdorff, the productive
> mathematician, and as Paul Mongré. Under this pseudonym, Hausdorff
> enjoyed remarkable recognition within the German intelligentsia at the
> end of the 19th century as a writer, philosopher and socially critical
> essayist....Between 1897 and 1904, Hausdorff reached the peak of
> his literary-philosophical accomplishment: during this period, 18 of a
> total of 22 works were published under his pseudonym. These included
> the volume of aphorisms *Sant’ Ilario: Thoughts from Zarathrustra’s
> Country*, his critique *Das Chaos in kosmischer Auslese*, a book of poems
> entitled *Ekstases*, the farce *Der Arzt seiner Ehre*, as well as numerous
> essays....The play was Hausdorff’s greatest literary success, as it was
> performed over 300 times in 31 cities.

Answer (score 26):

I think that the name of [Archimedes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes) immediately springs to mind. Among its inventions are the block-and-tackle pulley systems based on the lever, the screw, the parabolic reflectors used to burn Roman ships attacking Syracuse, the mechanical planetarium.

Comment: The story of the parabolic reflectors used to burn Roman ships attacking Syracuse is not true. It  is a legend.

Comment: The story is in Polybius, Plutarch and Lucian of Samosata. The Wikipedia page on Archimedes says that there are still an ongoing debate about its truth; however, some models of reflectors  have been built demonstrating that the construction of such weapons was actually possible with the technology that Archimedes had at his disposal.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes

Comment: The wikipedia page mentions some experiments indeed but the weapon requires a lot of luck. A catapult or flaming arrows are far much easier to use for the same effect.

Answer (score 26):

Paul Painlevé was briefly prime minister of France on two separate occasions, as well as holding many other government posts including Minister of Defense. In mathematics, he is best remembered for his contributions to nonlinear differential equations.

Comment: I mentioned Painlevé in a comment on the answer that proposed Villani.

Comment: Before being mainly involved in politics (mostly $\ge 1910$), Painlevé had (1897-1906) a significant involvement in defending Alfred Dreyfus, see [Des mathématiciens dans l'affaire Dreyfus (French)](https://images.math.cnrs.fr/Des-mathematiciens-dans-l-affaire-Dreyfus.html)

Answer (score 25):

[Gauß](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss) contributed to the development of the telegraph.
Gauß was also an astronomer, [metrology engineer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heliotrope_(instrument)) and [land surveyor](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gau%C3%9Fsche_Landesaufnahme).

Comment: Really?????????

Comment: @C.F.G Well, I don't think it was the fundamental theorem of algebra or quadratic reciprocity that got his name attached to the unit of magnetic flux density.

Comment: Major inventions are not usually made by a single person (there were lightbulbs before Edison), and the telegraph is no exception. But Gauss made an essential contribution.

Comment: @C.F.G : Is it a coincidence that your initials are the same as Gauss's? If not, your astonishment is a bit amusing!

Comment: Some details are at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needle_telegraph#Gauss_and_Weber_telegraph

Answer (score 24):

[Frank Ryan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Ryan_(American_football)) earned a math PhD from Rice for the dissertation "Characterization of the set of asymptotic values of a function holomorphic in the unit disc." He published two fundamental papers on the set of asymptotic values of a function holomorphic in the unit disc in Duke Mathematical Journal. [the papers, not the unit disc, were in the journal] He was an assistant professor at the Case Institute of Technology, 1967-71. He has an Erdős number of 3. He was also a lecturer in mathematics at Yale University, 1977-86.

But he is best-known as a quarterback in the National Football League, 1958-70. He led the Cleveland Browns to an NFL title in 1964.

Comment: John Urschel played in the NFL for a couple of seasons, and has some publications in Mathematics.

Comment: Frank Ryan died earlier this week (thought people might like to know): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Ryan_(American_football)

Answer (score 24):

[Persi Diaconis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persi_Diaconis) is an accomplished magician, in addition to his mathematical career.

Answer (score 22):

[Martin Hairer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Hairer) has written a widely used professional audio editing software "Amadeus Pro" (https://www.hairersoft.com/).

Comment: It is amusing to note that if you find the message board for Amadeus you'll see that Martin still personally replies to every user's troubleshooting request (e.g. https://www.hairersoft.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=7697)

Comment: Martin Hairer is mentioned also here: [Mathematicians with both “very abstract” and “very applied” achievements](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349461/mathematicians-with-both-very-abstract-and-very-applied-achievements/427932#427932).

Answer (score 21):

I'm surprise no-one has mentioned Isaac Newton.  He spent almost half his career outside academia fighting against forgery at the Royal Mint.  He was also an MP and wrote a huge amount on biblical chronology, alchemy, and theology.

Answer (score 21):

Harald Bohr was a member of the Danish national football team for the 1908 Summer Olympics, where he won a silver medal. The semi-final against France was 17-1.

Comment: Interesting result!!!

Comment: Interestingly, Harald Bohr played professional football also together with his older brother, Niels, who also had a prominent science career.

Answer (score 19):

Ron Graham's mathematical work is probably familiar to most users of this website.

In his youth, he won a title as California state trampoline champion. In 1972 he was elected president of the International Jugglers' Association.

Comment: I think later on he also won regional titles in table tennis after getting destroyed by Erdos in a table tennis game and then deciding that he had to improve.

Comment: @Hol, D. J. Albers (1996) A Nice Genius, Math Horizons, 4:2, 18-23, DOI: 10.1080/10724117.1996.11974993, "[in 1963] I saw this rather senior guy of 50 [Erdos], already quite famous, playing ping-pong during one of the breaks. He asked me if I wanted to play and I agreed. He absolutely killed me! I had played casual ping-pong but I couldn't believe that this old guy had beaten me. ... I went back to New Jersey ... I bought a table, joined a club, started playing at Bell Labs, and in the State league. I eventually became the Bell Labs champion at ping-pong, and won one of the New Jersey titles."

Comment: Also, I think mathematics is the only subject where someone aged 50 is an ''old guy''.

Comment: @Hollis I think maybe Ron meant it was (relatively) old for ping-pong.

Answer (score 18):

[Nikolai Durov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikolai_Durov), who launched Telegram with his brother Pavel Durov, has [some](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338193/durov-approach-to-arakelov-geometry-and-mathbbf-1) [works](https://arxiv.org/abs/0704.2030) on Arakelov geometry.

Answer (score 17):

I think Greg Egan (sci-fi author) qualifies. He has a few papers on arxiv, and made the news for his work on [superpermutations](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Superpermutation), which motivates the title 'Mathematician'. He is also an occasional MO-user.

Comment: I think Egan would be a great answer to a different question, of people whose profession is not "mathematician" doing good maths

Comment: @YemonChoi why don't you ask that as a separate question? I'd answer Aubrey de Grey.

Comment: @NikWeaver : That question arguably [already exists](https://mathoverflow.net/q/44244).

Comment: @TimothyChow and Egan and de Grey are both answers there! Never mind, then.

Answer (score 16):

[Joseph Fourier](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Joseph-Baron-Fourier) was also an Egyptologist.

Comment: He was a bit more than just that.  Excerpts from hiw biography on wikipedia include: "He took a prominent part in his own district in promoting the French Revolution, serving on the local Revolutionary Committee. ... Fourier accompanied Napoleon Bonaparte on his Egyptian expedition ... Cut off from France by the British fleet, he organized the workshops on which the French army had to rely for their munitions of war ...  In 1801, Napoleon appointed Fourier Prefect (Governor) of the Department of Isère in Grenoble, where he oversaw road construction and other projects."

Comment: @HJRW Equally, one should also mention Gaspard Monge, who was on the same expedition to Egypt, similarly held political appointments during the Revolution and all the while also is known for his results in geometry and as being the father of optimal transport.

Answer (score 15):

I am on the fence regarding whether this question should stay open, but while it does, I thought the following example might be of interest:
Peter Rosenthal, perhaps best known to mathematicians for his work on subspace lattices of operator algebras (see e.g. his book with Heydar Radjavi), developed a 2nd career/mission as a lawyer.

Wikipedia link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Rosenthal

Link from comments: [2014 profile in the Toronto Star](https://www.thestar.com/news/crime/2014/01/05/peter_rosenthals_passions_for_law_and_math_make_for_a_beautiful_if_different_life.html)

Comment: While he definitely seems to be vocal about being left-wing, the causes he represent are more often regarding basic human rights than left-wing. E.g., he has represented many cases of police brutality; see this beautiful piece on Toronto Star: https://www.thestar.com/news/crime/2014/01/05/peter_rosenthals_passions_for_law_and_math_make_for_a_beautiful_if_different_life.html

Comment: @auniket thank you for the clarification. I must admit that originally I omitted the adjective and then added it at the last-minute in a confused effort at sign-posting, since I couldn't remember the details that I'd heard from friends on the Canadian scene

Answer (score 15):

[Per Enflo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per_Enflo), a Swedish mathematician known for solving the so called ``basis problem'', one of the problems from Scottish book (about the existence of Schauder basis). Besides being a mathematician he is also known as a talented pianist.

Comment: I will add a link to [another answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369672/prominent-non-mathematical-work-of-mathematicians/371736#371736) about Per Enflo.

Answer (score 15):

[Otto Iulievich Schmidt](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Schmidt_Otto/) is now best remembered for his polar expeditions and a geophysical institute in Russia bears his name. The English wikipedia does not mention it, but he was also one of the founders of the modern theory of groups and had a strong influence on A.G. Kurosh.

Comment: Oh -- that's the Schmidt from Krull-Remak-Schmidt!

Comment: In the late 1950s, I had a textbook on group theory written by O.J.Schmidt (in Russian). It was very nice.

Answer (score 14):

Mathematician [**Eric Temple Bell**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_Temple_Bell)

> President of the MAA, 1931-32
> Author of the book *Men of Mathematics*
> Bell numbers, Bell polynomials
> etc.

Also was a successful science fiction author under the pseudonym **John Taine**.

See the fascinating book
Reid, Constance, *The Search for E.T. Bell*, MAA spectrum, The Mathematical Association of America, 1993

Answer (score 14):

[Richard Garfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Garfield) is a mathematician and former math professor who is nowadays famous as the inventor of the wildly successful card game Magic: The Gathering, and many other card and board games. Here is what Wikipedia says about his math background:

> After college, he joined Bell Laboratories, but soon after decided to continue his education and attended the University of Pennsylvania, studying combinatorial mathematics for his PhD. Garfield studied under Herbert Wilf and earned a Ph.D. in combinatorial mathematics from Penn in 1993. His thesis was On the Residue Classes of Combinatorial Families of Numbers. Shortly thereafter, he became a professor of mathematics at Whitman College in Walla Walla, Washington.

A colleague of mine who is somewhat knowledgeable about Magic: The Gathering once claimed that the game became as successful as it was because it was invented by a mathematician who systematically set out to create the most addictive game possible. I cannot say how much truth there is to that claim.

Comment: It is odd that there are 4 magician in the answers!!

Comment: Years ago, I visited a Penn math professor who complained that the graduate students were spending all their time in the department lounge playing card games.

Comment: Years ago when I was at Cambridge the graduate students spent their time in the department lounge playing Conway games.

Answer (score 12):

In addition to his work in number theory, [Carl Størmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_St%C3%B8rmer) made important contributions to the study of the *aurora borealis*. Here he is conducting an experiment rather far from his blackboard:

[image: Størmer conducting an experiment]

Comment: Størmer was awarded the 1922 Janssen Medal of the Paris Academy of Sciences for his work on the aurora. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janssen_Medal_(French_Academy_of_Sciences)

Answer (score 11):

[Gian-Carlo Rota](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gian-Carlo_Rota) in addition to being an influential combinatorialist was a philosopher, and his philosophical writing was not in the tradition often thought of as being closest to math ('analytic philosophy') but was rather inspired by phenomenology. Apparently this heterodoxy caused some consternation from e.g. his colleagues in the philosophy department at MIT.

Answer (score 10):

[Alexander Esenin-Volpin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Esenin-Volpin) was a mathematician well-known for his work as a Soviet political dissident.

**EDIT:** I'm sorry for writing the above so glibly. Among other things, Esenin-Volpin was repeatedly imprisoned or else confined to mental institutions for political reasons -- according to wikipedia he spent 6 years cumulatively in either of those situations. I'd love if somebody more competent than I would write something more informative and fitting.

Comment: The same can be said about Shafarevich too

Comment: Can't resist mentioning a non-answer to the question: someone prominent for non-mathematical work who was a maths+physics student at university: https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/literature/1970/solzhenitsyn/biographical/

Comment: There was a gulf of difference between Esenin-Volpin and Schafarevich; it'd be simpler to remember Schafarewich as an outstanding mathematician and let's mercifully forget about the rest of his story.

Comment: @WlodAA I did not say that they are similar in any other respect, except that "was a mathematician well-known for his work as a Soviet political dissident" applies to both; maybe it'd be also simpler to remember only part of what we happen to remember, so let's mercifully forget about the rest of it?

Answer (score 10):

[René Descartes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Descartes#Mathematical_legacy)

Mathematically you're likely to know him for Cartesian geometry.

Philosophers will know him for "[Cogito, ergo sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cogito,_ergo_sum)"/"Je pense, donc je suis"

Quoting wikipedia: "Descartes is also widely regarded as one of the founders of modern philosophy." I suspect, as with Russell, people might argue Descartes was a philosopher who did a little mathematics, but ignoring the eponym of Cartesian coordinates is too hard to do.

Comment: Rene Descartes walks into a bar and orders a drink. When he finishes his drink, the bartender asks him if he would like another. Descartes replies, “No, I think not,” and disappears in a puff of logic.

Comment: I think Descartes did  more than "a little" Mathematics

Comment: I agree, I was just attempting to preempt similar comments to the Bertrand Russell (https://mathoverflow.net/a/369713/164087) answer.

Comment: Descartes did much more than systematising the $(x,y)$-coordinates. It is worthwile to read his essay "La géométrie", where among other things he studies some plane curves and without much overstating prefigures algebraic geometry.

Answer (score 10):

[Emily Riehl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emily_Riehl) is a professor of mathematics at Johns Hopkins. She does transformative work in abstract homotopy theory, and has [won many grants](https://hub.jhu.edu/2020/01/16/emily-riehl-mathematics-frontier-award-999-em1-art1-dtd-news/). She is also a [professional Australian rules football player](https://usafl.com/player/emily-riehl).

Answer (score 10):

[Ruggero Freddi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlo_Masi) is an Italian mathematics lecturer (holding a PhD) and a former gay pornographic film actor known professionally as Carlo Masi. Here you can read his [thesis](https://iris.uniroma1.it/retrieve/handle/11573/1364660/1365546/Tesi_dottorato_Freddi.pdf).

Comment: this is not work of a mathematician.

Comment: @C.F.G Sorry, but now you will have to justify and explain to me why exactly do you consider that Freddi or its previous work do not qualify to be answers to what you asked. I pretty much think that it fits in both of your questions (specially the second). He is a mathematician and did "famous" work out of mathematics (unless you think that gay porn is mathematics). There is a dichotomy that I do not understand (in fact, I do but I want to expose you). So either you consider that acting in gay porn is a job or you consider that Freddi is not a mathematician. You will have to be more clear...

Comment: He was not a mathematician during in his previous work.

Comment: @C.F.G He was actually forming himself to be one and in your question you never mentioned that these works have to happen at the same time. In fact, this restriction would not allow several previous answers. E.g., this would eliminate some you own answer of Glen Bredon. Villani would not qualify either because he stopped doing math (for the moment). 
S

Comment: So either your question is ill posed and thus it should be closed because it already attracted answers that you did not mean or your problem is other.

Comment: @C.F.G I am going to tell you what I think. If you consider that being gay porn actor is not a job you are plainly wrong. Otherwise, the possibility is that you consider that Freddi is not a mathematician, which is quite problematic given the fact that he holds a PhD degree based in the linked thesis. Having a PhD generally mean that you did research work in Maths and it is more than enough to be considered as a mathematician. So, unless you found a flaw in the thesis of Freddi (and even in this hypothetical case), he qualifies to your question. However, I think that your problem is different.

Comment: All posts you mentioned first were mathematician then they become or did other thing.

Comment: @C.F.G I really think that your question is educative and deserve to stay so I will not vote to close. Your question is a place to see that one can become mathematician from other interests and can be a mathematician and something else. However, I think that having a gay porn actor in this wiki is problematic for you. I really hope that you explain yourself better. Your downvote and your comment have not being correctly justified yet and I wish that the problem does not relate to the fact that he is gay or porn actor (sadly I think that it does). It is pretty sad seeing this mentality here.

Comment: This reminds me that Catalan mathematician and logician Angel García-Cerdaña (Cerdanya) is also a known TV actor. Am I to understand that for some reason he does not qualify for this question either?

Comment: @C.F.G Again, in your question you never mentioned that this order was necessary to keep. Your question is literally "Are there mathematicians who have done outstanding/prominent non-mathematical work like inventions, patents, solving social/economical/etc. problems, papers in these areas, etc.?" Where is the restriction that are now mentioning exactly? I don’t see it. Freddi, mathematician and former gay porn actor and gay porn actor is a non-mathematical job as I see it.

Comment: You can ask a new post like "prominent non-mathematicians later become mathematician" if you are interested in. But this is distinct from mine. so pls do not comment anymore.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Sadly, I think that "being gay" and "appearing naked in TV" is the real problem here.

Comment: It's hard to interpret the downvotes on this answer as anything other than narrow-minded prejudice. Would it have been downvoted if Freddi had been a  Shakespearean stage actor?

Comment: There are other people listed who did much of their non-mathematical work before they became mathematicians. This includes Persi Diaconis, Danica McKellar, and Frank Ryan

Comment: @TomLeinster : I did not downvote or upvote. Narrow-minded prejudice is certainly one possible explanation for the downvote. However, I just checked several other answers, and there are downvotes in several cases which cannot be explained by prejudice (in the sense you mean it). The pattern seems to be that if the achievement is either not obviously "prominent and outstanding" or if it deviates too far from "inventions, patents, solving social/economical/etc. problems, papers" then it might attract a downvote. For example, as I write this, I note that Grothendieck attracted a downvote.

Answer (score 10):

Benjamin F. Logan was primarily an electrical engineer who spent his career at Bell Labs, but he has 37 publications listed in Mathematical Reviews. His best known mathematical work is his 1977 paper with Larry Shepp, [A variational problem for random Young tableaux](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870877900305?via%3Dihub), in which they proved that if $L_n$ is the expected length  of the longest increasing sequence in a randomly chosen permutation of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} L_n/\sqrt{n}\ge 2$.

Long ago when I used to go to bluegrass festivals, I sometimes saw a bluegrass fiddler named Tex Logan who played with Peter Rowan then, but had earlier played with such greats as Mike Seeger, Bill Monroe, and The Lilly Brothers & Don Stover. Tex Logan also wrote songs recorded by Johnny Cash, Emmylou Harris, and Bob Dylan.

It wasn't until many years later that I learned that B. F. Logan and Tex Logan were the same person.

Answer (score 9):

Another politician would be [Éamon de Valera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89amon_de_Valera), who graduated in mathematics and taught at various schools (and applied for a professorship, but without success), but then became a rather influential Irish politician.

Answer (score 9):

[Alexander Grothendieck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Grothendieck) was a [political activist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Grothendieck#Political_activism) and [spiritualist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Grothendieck#Manuscripts_written_in_the_1980s).

Comment: this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 9):

[Raymond Smullyan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raymond_Smullyan) was a

> mathematician, magician, concert pianist, logician, Taoist, and philosopher.

Answer (score 9):

I think, one can add Francesco Faa di Bruno to this list, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francesco_Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno. He is to my knowledge the only beatified mathematician.

Answer (score 8):

Jerry McNerney ([Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerry_McNerney)) is a US congressperson from California, with a PhD in differential geometry.

Nowadays he's more known as a congressman than as a mathematician, but every now and then he will give quick floor speeches about math or mathematicians.

See, e.g., his [tribute](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mdlEPk3m4es) to Mirzakhani.

Answer (score 8):

Dutch mathematician [Alexander Rinnooy Kan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Rinnooy_Kan) is also a politician and businessman. He used to be a member of the board of directors of ING Group, served as the Chairman of the Social and Economic Council that advises the government, and was a member of the senate.

[According to a national newspaper](https://web.archive.org/web/20101215163224/http://nos.nl/artikel/112743-rinnooy-kan-weer-invloedrijkste-nederlander.html), he was the most influential person in the Netherlands in 2007, 2008, and 2009.

Answer (score 7):

[Boris Berezovsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boris_Berezovsky_(businessman)), a Russian oligarch and government official, was a professional mathematician.

Answer (score 7):

[Tony Scholl](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthony_Scholl) is also a bassist with the Cambridge Philharmonic.

Answer (score 7):

I've seen a couple of mentions of Emanuel Lasker, a former world chess champion.  Here's his non-mathematical academic works, which include a play "History of Mankind" cowritten with his brother:

Kampf (Struggle), 1906.
Das Begreifen der Welt (Comprehending the World), 1913.
Die Philosophie des Unvollendbar (sic; The Philosophy of the Unattainable), 1918.
Vom Menschen die Geschichte ("History of Mankind"), 1925 – a play, co-written with his brother Berthold.
The Community of the Future, 1940.

In his "Kampf" he foresaw the application of game theory in 20th century social sciences.  He also wrote on other games besides chess as well.  Here's a list of those books.

Encyclopedia of Games, 1929.
Das verständige Kartenspiel (Sensible Card Play), 1929 – English translation published in the same year.
Brettspiele der Völker (Board Games of the Nations), 1931 – includes sections about Go and Lasca.
Das Bridgespiel ("The Game of Bridge"), 1931.

Also, don't forget Max Euwe.  Max Euwe was also world chess champion and president of FIDE (the international chess body).  Dr. Euwe wrote on the Thue-Morse sequence and it implying that, according to the rules of chess at the time, a game could be played as an infinite game without resolution under certain circumstances.  He taught mathematics at one point and was a professor of computer science at the Universities of Rotterdam and Tillberg.

Comment: I read somewhere that Max Euwe won some kind of amateur boxing title. Is that true?

Comment: http://members.tripod.com/HSK_Chess/euwe.html

I'd never heard of this before, but it is true.  The link is confirmation.

He also didn't play chess professionally, but still won the world championship.

Comment: It was the amateur boxing championship of Europe that Euwe won.  I don't have a year though.

Answer (score 7):

[Daniel Biss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Biss) received his PhD in mathematics at MIT in 2002, then was an Assistant Professor at the University of Chicago until 2008. He won the 1999 Morgan Prize for outstanding research as an undergraduate. However, in 2007, a serious flaw was discovered that destroyed the main results of papers he had published in the Annals of Mathematics and in Advances. He is now a State Senator in Illinois. In this position, he has worked on legislation to "allow for automatic voter registration," to "elect a number of statewide offices by ranked-choice ballot," and on healthcare, among other things.

Answer (score 7):

[Sergio Fajardo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergio_Fajardo), the former mayor of the Colombian city of Medellín, wrote a dozen papers in model theory before switching to politics.

Comment: Crap, I accidentally duplicated this answer in 2021

Answer (score 6):

[Claude Elwood Shannon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_Shannon#Hobbies_and_inventions) was also an inventor. I recall he also invented a rocket-powered pair of boots, but I cannot seem to find the source anymore.

Answer (score 6):

The numerical analyst, Manil Suri, is also an accomplished novelist. He has written a trilogy of novels. The first of which, The Death of Vishnu, was long listed for the Booker
Prize.

Comment: I don't understand why this is down voted. He's a quite accomplished mathematician (https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=lFWFsSkAAAAJ&hl=en&oi=ao) and an award winning novelist. Seems to fit well.

Answer (score 6):

[Sergio Fajardo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergio_Fajardo) is a mathematician who was also Mayor of Medellin after the death of Pablo Escobar, was Governor of Antioquia (the state that Medellin is in) from 2012–2016, ran for President of Colombia in 2018, and has announced plans to run again for President. In mathematics, he earned his PhD from UW-Madison and was a professor at the Universidad de los Andes and the Universidad Nacional of Colombia.

In politics, he completely revitalized the city of Medellin, building new parks and libraries, and rebranding the city. The Park of Lights is a great example. That park used to be (figuratively) the darkest place in the city. Escobar had complete control of it and any (non-corrupt) police officer who came nearby would be killed. The park contains two of the oldest buildings in the city, and they were full of squatters. Now, the park is full of life, with Colombian bamboo (Guada kindiana), tons of people, and these giant lightsaber-looking lights that run all night. It's never dark there. It's the safest place in the city. The buildings that used to house squatters now house the department of education. Fajardo also built beautiful libraries to serve the poorest neighborhoods of the city, to give children a chance at a life based around something other than drugs.  He was named "best Mayor of Medellin" in 2007. Regarding his time as governor, according to Wikipedia

> During his administration, Antioquia experienced the best national performance in open government, transparency and investment of oil royalties (according to the National Planning Department and the Anti corruption Office of Colombia). He was named the best governor of the country in 2015 by the organization Colombia Líder.

Answer (score 6):

[Vladimir Voevodsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Voevodsky). He won a Fields Medal for inventing motivic homotopy theory and proving the Milnor Conjecture and in his later years worked on homotopy type theory.

He was a world-class photographer. This is mentioned in [his "in memoriam" by Friedlander](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2018-55-04/S0273-0979-2018-01636-4/S0273-0979-2018-01636-4.pdf) and you can also see [some of his photos](https://www.ias.edu/photography-institute-woods) hosted by IAS. On that page, it mentions that his photography was included in a 2011 exhibit. I've heard that some of his photos were published by top magazines, like National Geographic, but I don't know all the details. If anyone else does, please add!

Answer (score 5):

[Nasīr al-Dīn al-Tūsī](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasir_al-Din_al-Tusi) was a persian polymath of thirteenth century. His contribution to trigonometry includes the plane law of sines. He had a prominent place in the court of [Hulagu Khan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulagu_Khan) (a grandson of Genghis Khan and the founder of the Ilkhanate Empire), and benefited from Khan's patronage to found the [Maragheh Observatory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maragheh_observatory). The legend even has it that he was influential in persuading Hulagu to siege Baghdad in 1258 which ended the 500 years old [Abbasid Caliphate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbasid_Caliphate).

Answer (score 5):

[Gunnar Carlsson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunnar_Carlsson) is a professor at Stanford famous for his work in K-theory, and on the Segal Conjecture in homotopy theory. He is also the President and Founder of the company [Ayasdi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayasdi), described as

> A machine intelligence software company that offers a software platform and applications to organizations looking to analyze and build predictive models using big data or highly dimensional data sets. Organizations and governments have deployed Ayasdi's software across a variety of use cases including the development of clinical pathways for hospitals, anti-money laundering, fraud detection, trading strategies, customer segmentation, oil and gas well development, drug development, disease research, information security, anomaly detection, and national security applications.

Answer (score 5):

Although John Urschel is already mentioned in a comment to the answer about Frank Ryan, I think he deserves his own answer. Urschel was a football player first at Penn State and then with the Baltimore Ravens. He majored in math at Penn State and then, allegedly without the knowledge of the Baltimore Ravens, enrolled in the MIT math PhD program. Urschel will receive his PhD in spring 2021 and already has an [impressive list of publications](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=WQ_l2-0AAAAJ&hl=en&oi=sra)

Comment: He wasn't a mathematician before or during playing football?

Comment: Based on the years of his publications, it appears that he did write research math papers while he was playing football at Penn State and then for the Baltimore Ravens. Given the physical and mental energy, as well as the time needed each week to prepare for a football game, this is quite remarkable.

Answer (score 4):

Merely meant as an interesting and amusing fact. People are not born as mathematicians. At the age of 14, long time before his mathematical career and winning the Fields medal, **Wendelin Werner** played a role in 'The Passerby' at the side of Romy Schneider. She died a few weeks after the movie premiere.

Comment: "People are not born as mathematicians." -- Some do.

Comment: We disagree. That's fine.

Answer (score 4):

[Art Benjamin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_T._Benjamin) is a professor of mathematics at Harvey Mudd College, with [more than 100 publications](https://math.hmc.edu/benjamin/research-papers/). He is also an accomplished magician and was the 1997 American Backgammon Tour Player of the Year.

Answer (score 4):

[Baruch Spinoza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baruch_Spinoza) was a mathematician, philosopher, and physicist "involved in important optical investigations of the day." His masterpiece, The *Ethics*, is "written with a forbidding mathematical structure modeled on Euclid's geometry." He was an early Enlightenment thinker of the Dutch Golden Age.

Answer (score 4):

[Alan Turing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Turing) is a mathematician famous for his contributions to the foundations of computer science, for being a codebreaker in WW2, and for being persecuted by the UK government for being homosexual. Readers have probably heard of the Turing test in artificial intelligence. I would argue that his contributions to computer science don't count as "non-mathematical work" but that his contributions to biology do. For example, his paper [The Chemical Basis of Morphogenesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chemical_Basis_of_Morphogenesis) is highly cited and is the reason the name "Turing patterns" is used to describe zebrafish embryos.

Answer (score 4):

[Hans Freudenthal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Freudenthal) was a famous topologist. Indeed, the Freudenthal suspension theorem is the foundational result you need to get stable homotopy theory off the ground. He also invented a language, [Lincos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lincos_language), "to make possible communication with extraterrestrial intelligence." And he invented [a famous puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_and_Product_Puzzle). And an asteroid is named after him.

Comment: The famous puzzle looks pretty mathematical (though not topological) itself.

Answer (score 4):

[Per Enflo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per_Enflo) is famous for solving Banach's basis problem, Grothendieck's approximation problem, and the invariant subspace problem for general Banach spaces, and has other fundamental research in linear  and non linear geometric functional analysis. He also has done research in population dynamics. A child prodigy as a pianist, he continues to give concerts in Europe and the United States, but you can hear him at home by creating a Per Enflo station on Spotify.

Comment: There is such an answer (although less detailed) already: https://mathoverflow.net/a/369738/4312

Answer (score 4):

[Patrick Billingsley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrick_Billingsley), author of two well-known books in probability theory, was also a stage and [screen](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0082525/?ref_=fn_nm_nm_12) actor.

Comment: Whoa. [Preston & Logan, 1989]

Answer (score 3):

Doctor [Ahmed Chalabi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahmed_Chalabi) earned a [PhD](https://mathgenealogy.org/id.php?id=6597) from the University of Chicago in 1969, founded [Petra Bank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petra_Bank) in 1977, was sentenced in absentia in Jordan for [bank fraud](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/not_in_website/syndication/monitoring/media_reports/2291649.stm) in 1992, and (allegedly) very successfully lobbied for the [2003 Invasion of Iraq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2003_invasion_of_Iraq).

Comment: I think this one falls more under the "prominent figure who has a PhD in mathematics" category (as do a number of the other posts, to be fair)- but, wow! this guy has a wild life story!

Comment: @SamHopkins Indeed. However, I assume that the University of Chicago would not have granted him a doctoral degree had he not made a non-trivial contribution. Perhaps I assume too much.

Answer (score 3):

The book by French mathematician Jacques Hadamard, *[The Psychology of Invention in the Mathematical Field](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1454428.The_Psychology_of_Invention_in_the_Mathematical_Field)*.
The book discusses the four stages of thought:

1. Preparation (conscious work setting up the problem and trying to solve it)
2. Incubation (no conscious work on the problem)
3. Illumination (the fruits of incubation where an insight is received) and finally
4. Verification (consciously testing and verifying the insight)

Gromov's Ergobrain Program for Universal learning program:

- Mischa Gromov, *Great Circle of Mysteries: Mathematics, the World, the Mind*, Springer (2018) doi:[10.1007/978-3-319-53049-9](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-53049-9) (see also the [essay of the same name](https://www.ihes.fr/%7Egromov/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/circle-of-mysteries-nov13-2015.pdf) from 2015).

Answer (score 3):

[Danica McKellar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danica_McKellar) may not qualify as a mathematician, but (all quotes below are from Wikipedia)

McKellar studied at the University of California, Los Angeles where she earned a Bachelor of Science degree summa cum laude in Mathematics in 1998. As an undergraduate, she coauthored a scientific paper with Professor Lincoln Chayes and fellow student Brandy Winn titled "Percolation and Gibbs states multiplicity for ferromagnetic Ashkin–Teller models on ${\bf Z}^2$." Their results are termed the "Chayes–McKellar–Winn theorem". Later, when Chayes was asked to comment about the mathematical abilities of his student coauthors, he was quoted in The New York Times, "I thought that the two were really, really first-rate." For her past collaborative work on research papers, McKellar is currently assigned the Erdős number four, and her Erdős–Bacon number is six.

Also, she

wrote six non-fiction books, all dealing with mathematics: Math Doesn't Suck, Kiss My Math, Hot X: Algebra Exposed, Girls Get Curves: Geometry Takes Shape, which encourage middle-school and high-school girls to have confidence and succeed in mathematics, Goodnight, Numbers, and Do Not Open This Math Book.

Her acting career, in brief:

She played Winnie Cooper in the television series The Wonder Years from 1988–1993, and since 2010 has voiced Miss Martian in the animated superhero series Young Justice.

In 2015, McKellar was cast in the Netflix original series Project Mc2. She appears in several television films for Hallmark Channel. She is the current voice of Judy Jetson from The Jetsons since 2017 following Janet Waldo's death in 2016.

Answer (score 3):

[Glen E. Bredon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glen_Bredon) is the author of the programs  DOS.MASTER for Apple II computers, [Merlin (a macro assembler)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merlin_(assembler)) and ProSel for Apple machines. He was the professor of mathematics at Berkley and IAS and author of worthwhile math books like

*Bredon, Glen E.*, Topology and geometry., Graduate Texts in Mathematics. 139. Berlin: Springer. xiv, 557 p. (1997). [ZBL0934.55001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0934.55001).

and

*Bredon, Glen E.*, Introduction to compact transformation groups, Pure and Applied Mathematics, 46. New York-London: Academic Press. XIII,459 p. $ 21.00 (1972). [ZBL0246.57017](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0246.57017).

Answer (score 3):

Not so prominent I think but I'd like to mention that the *MathTime Professional 2* ([MTPro2](https://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html)) fonts were designed by Michael Spivak of Publish or Perish Inc., [see here](https://www.pctex.com/files/managed/5/55/MTProAnnals.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

It has been [noted](https://mathoverflow.net/a/369677/8628) already that [Noam Elkies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noam_Elkies) is an accomplished composer.

What I find at least as extraordinary about him is that he can hum-whistle some of Bach's [two-part inventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inventions_and_Sinfonias_(Bach)). (Anecdotal "evidence", will remove this answer if it is false.)

Answer (score 3):

Marcel-Paul Schuetzenberger (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcel-Paul_Sch%C3%BCtzenberger) is also an interesting example (he started as a physician).

Answer (score 3):

James Garfield submitted an original proof of Pythagoras's theorem to the  *New-England Journal of Education* and which was published in the April 1, 1876 issue.

He taught the liberal arts and practised law, he was also a brigadier-general in the Civil War.

He was also the 20th President of the USA, inaugurated in 1881. He developed the proof whilst a member of Congress.

Comment: I'm not sure that publishing an original proof of Pythagoras qualifies someone as a mathematician.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: What does these days? Some people think that only if you dedicate your life to research level maths makes you a mathematician. I take a broader view. But then I'm a democrat.

Answer (score 2):

[Andrew Blumberg](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/blumberg/index.html#), in addition to being an accomplished homotopy theorist, a [full professor at UT Austin](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/blumberg/cv.pdf), and having [published more than 60 papers](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/blumberg/publication-list.pdf), also works on issues related to geolocation data and privacy. For example, [he worked on an amicus brief for a Supreme Court case](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/blumberg/jones.html).

Answer (score 2):

I learned this answer from [another thread](https://mathoverflow.net/a/349488/11540) where the OP said it didn't quite fit.

Frank Garside did important work in the 1960s related to braid groups. He also invented what is now known as the [Garside element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garside_element), leading to Garside groups. Later, he was the mayor of Oxford.

In a related vein, George Reid was an algebraist who was later mayor of Cambridge in 1990-91.

Comment: My memory from my (long ago) days in Cambridge is that George Reid was more of an analyst (Banach algebras?) than an algebraist.

Comment: I confess I just copied the other answer. I don't know much about Reid's work at all. His thesis was about topological groups: https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=26731 Also, here's a link to his later work in government: https://aru.ac.uk/about-us/governance/strategy-and-leadership/board-of-governors/george-reid

Comment: Which Cambridge?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some [mathematical work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_manuscripts_of_Karl_Marx) by someone better known for other work.

Comment: Isn't this the exact reverse of what the question is asking for?

Comment: @YemonChoi Indeed, this answer should be reformulated as “Karl Marx wrote political texts that have gained some measure of celebrity”. 

Comment: Does any of this go beyond philosophical ramblings about basic definitions? Legit question -- I haven't seen the entire work.

Comment: [Karl Marx and the Foundations of Differential Calculus](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82390314.pdf) by Hubert Kennedy gives a nice discussion of Marx's investigations into calculus. At the time, the received view of the derivative (following Leibniz) was a ratio of infinitesimals, which today we would find lacking in rigor. Marx perceived this difficulty and took some nontrivial steps toward a modern rigorous account.

Answer (score 1):

[Abu Rayhan al-Biruni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Biruni) (973 – after 1050) was an Iranian polymath,  physicist, astronomer, natural sciences, historian, chronologist and linguist. One of the best his achievements is a method proposed and used by him to estimate the radius and circumference of the Earth almost 1000 years ago.

He was also inventor of minutes and seconds of time.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Charles Kalme](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Charles_Kalme), a mathematician (Contributions to the Theory of Discontinuous Groups of Mobius Transformations, Ph.D. thesis, NYU, 1967) and pioneering chess programmer. His achievements as a chessplayer include winning the United States Junior Championship and playing twice in the United States Chess Championship. He was also a master of contract bridge.

Comment: The well-known mathematician Henry Peter Francis Swinnerton-Dyer was also an outstanding chess and bridge player in his student days. A variation in Ponziani's Opening that he played in 1949 is cited in 10th edition of Modern Chess Openings.

Answer (score 1):

There is Bertrand Russell, a logician, who had another career as a philosopher as well as an anti-war protestor. He helped publicise what was happening in Vietnam - in fact, according to Paul McCartney of the Beatles, at one point he lived on the same square or street with Russell and he had knocked on his door to introduce himself and Russell proceeded to tell him all about the war. This is, according to Paul McCartney, how the Beatles became involved in the anti-war protest movement, in particularly against the war of aggression by the USA on Vietnam.

Laurent Schwartz, a french mathematician known for his work was on distributions, was also an anti-war activist and who focused on labour activism as well on the colonial war in Algeria.

Grothendieck, who needs no introduction, was also an ati-war activist, focusing on what was then occuring Vietnam. His fater was a revolutionary socialist.

Smale was also another anti-war activist; also Solzhenitsyn and many others.

Sofia Kovalevskaya was one of the first handful of female mathematicians. She was also a writer, having written a well-received autobiography, *A Russian Childhood* in where she reveals she met Dostoyevsky as a young woman and did not think much of him.

Likewise, Lewis Carroll, also a logician and who wrote the best-selling *Alice's Adventures in Wonderland*.

Also Abdus Salam, who was a mathematical physicist and had a second career setting up the Triest Centre of Mathematical Physics to help te Third World get on to its feet.

And a special mention for Walter Sisulu, who studied a science degree, but after joining the ANC, was imprisoned several times, and was finally imprisoned on Robbens Island with Nelson Mandela and sentenced to twenty-five years - the same sentence as Nelson. He rose to become the ANC's Secretary-General and Deputy President of the organisation.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/a/369713/90655

Comment: Russell is previously mentioned [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/369713/8133). Carroll is mentioned [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/369674/8133).

Comment: @Noah Schweber: But with very little detail - they deserve better than that. Besides Kovalevskaya and Sisulu are not mentioned.

Comment: Solzhenitsyn was not a mathematician. Carroll hardly one, to be honest. Sisulu only studied science, but never worked as a mathematician. There are many students in mathematics (the majority, in fact) who pursue careers not related to mathematics after graduation, so according to your view they would all qualify as answers to this question.

Comment: @AlexM: Carroll nevertheless was a logician.

Comment: @AlexM: Wot about Abdus Salam - are you going to complain about him too?

Comment: This is a *community wiki big-list* question for a reason. (1) If you feel some other answer has insufficient detail, add that detail *to that answer*, do not put it in a new answer. (2) Ideally, each answer should only give *one* example. If you have more people, put each in a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Stan Wagon](http://www.stanwagon.com/), whose work was featured in several Mathoverflow posts (e.g. [an unexpected image](https://mathoverflow.net/a/178359/1508), [Gaussian prime spirals](https://mathoverflow.net/a/92558/1508)), has also [an entry](http://stanwagon.com/public/RipleysWithCopyrightNotice.jpg) in *Ripley's Believe It or Not* due to his Square Wheel Bike.

Answer (score 0):

I think, [John F. Nash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Forbes_Nash_Jr.) fits in this category,  because of 1994  Nobel Memorial Prize in Economic Sciences. (I am not aware the details of his work, I just know this because of "[A beautiful mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Beautiful_Mind_(book))" movie!)

Comment: The work Nash received the Nobel memorial prize for was from his Princeton PhD-thesis in mathematics. This was not non-mathematical work.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: thanks for comment. So I should delete this answer but I think it is better to not to do that for those don't know this fact like me!!

Answer (score 0):

Although it is difficult to say exactly what Thales accomplished, if you take what he's given credit for it is immense.  By your criteria he would qualify as an answer.

Although he lacked the rigor of proof, he was the first mathematician we attribute a mathematical result to - namely Thales' Theorem used to get the distances of ships at sea.

He was also the first philosopher.  With his contention that everything is water we have the first theory that says everything is one.

Also with his contention that everything is water we have a testable claim.  This makes him the first scientist.

He also was an astronomer, predicting the eclipse of May 28th, 585 BC.

He even dabbled in business, by legend.  There is a famous story attributed to Aristotle, and others, about him.  If true, Thales predicted the weather and foresaw a good olive harvest for the coming year.  He then bought all the olive presses at a discount, and rented them out during the harvest.  This would be the first recorded use of futures to turn a profit.

Legend has it that Thales was an engineer.

Comment: I think Joseph of Genesis preceded Thales in the use of futures. Seven good years, followed by seven lean years, and all that. But there's no record of Joseph making any mathematical contributions, Thales has him beat there.

Comment: Wikipedia is incorrect then.  I've also seen other sources that cite Thales as well.  

The old testament reached its current form in the Persian period (538-332 BC).  Thales came before that.  I suppose if you believe the Bible is to be taken as a real account, then that reference would be older.  However, I don't think you'll find a scholar that would argue that Thales wasn't real.

Comment: Wikipedia? Who said anything about Wikipedia?

Comment: From wikipedia, with their source on the topic:  "This first version of the story would constitute the first historically known creation and use of futures, whereas the second version would be the first historically known creation and use of options."

George Crawford, Bidyut Sen – Derivatives for Decision Makers: Strategic Management Issues, John Wiley & Sons, 1996 ISBN 9780471129943

Answer (score 0):

Albert Einstein's contribution to differential geometry was significant. One could mention also Einstein's tensor notation.

On the other hand, Einstein was an inventor, he had several inventions (patents) to his credit.

Comment: He wasn't a mathematician I think.

Comment: If you forget that Albert Einstein was a physicist, you will see that he was a strong research mathematician (more than so many mentioned in this thread).

Comment: One of his papers on math?

Comment: Mathematics can be recorded also outside of papers in mathematical journals. Differential geometers would direct you to Einstein's results on the affine connection.

Comment: The probability theory, classical mechanics, the special relativity theory, ... ... ...  are all mathematical theories these days.

Comment: What is the definition of a mathematician? Who is educated in math or did some math research. Isn't?

Comment: Forget "educated". It's the mathematical research impact that counts. Thus, it'd be silly to skip Einstein in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Professionally, Pierre de Fermat was a lawyer; he had also contributed to physics.

Henry Poincare, Solomon Lefschetz, and Raoul Boot were into engineering when they were young.

Hugo Steinhaus was serious about applications, e.g. about the different feet shapes in order to help shoe designers. The famous Steinhaus slogan was

***A mathematician will do it better.***

In particular, Steinhaus patented longimeter.

Karol Borsuk invented a successful game during WWII, and it helped him to survive in those hardship years.

Stan (Stanisław) Ulam was the main inventor of the H bomb. He has also invented cellular automata.

Israel Gelfand at his mature stage turned his interests toward biology and medicine.

Rene Thom in his later years became seriously interested in too many things to mention here.

Several American mathematicians, including John Milnor, worked on DOD contracts.

Topologist James Munkres made a significant contribution to the assignment problem -- it's even called Munkres assignment algorithm or Kuhn–Munkres algorithm.

A parallel processor invented by a mathematician in the US, and the technology that followed, had an impact on the fall of communism.

Greg Kuperberg was an early pioneer in the field of computer games when he was in his teens; this helped him to pay his tuition at MIT.

Comment: Did Fermat do anything prominent as a lawyer? Did Poincare, Lefschetz, Bott do anything prominent when they were "into" engineering? Did Thom do anything prominent in the unmentionable areas that interested him? Did Milnor et al do nonmathematical things on those DoD contracts? Isn't the assignment problem mathematics? Any details on the mathematician who invented a parallel processor, and how it impacted communism?

Comment: @GerryMyerso, it's mixed. OP said *outstanding/prominent*. But there were over 30 answers before mine, and the average level for these 30+ is way below *outstanding/prominent*, and overall I believe that also clearly below my answer. ### My weakest case was wonderful Bott who indeed was simply an engineering student. ... Munkres did an algorithm (Erdos would call it computer science, not mathematics).

Answer (score -2):

I see nobody mentioned about John Forbes Nash, who obtained `Nobel prize` in Economic science for his contribution to economy. Further German Mathematician Carl Fredric Gauss, Von Neumann etc both were not only prominent mathematicians but also prominent physicist as well.

Comment: Gauss was already mentioned, https://mathoverflow.net/posts/369701/revisions (I think von Neumann was already mentioned, too).

Comment: @GerryMyerson, But Prof John Nash was not mentioned.

Comment: Actually, Nash was mentioned in this answer of C.F.G: https://mathoverflow.net/a/369703

Comment: @JeremyRickard, I am confused who answered first , he or me.I answered 10 hours ago. During my answer i searched with keyword `nash` but got no link. That is why i answered as you see my first sentence. Anyway let it remain.I will help

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR: I posted [my answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/369703) 2 month ago.